# I want to pass data in codeigniter from view using ajax post, process that data in controller and send back the result array to view

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I have searched the whole WWW but get nothing helpful. Any Solution will be appreciated. thanks in advance

**MY HTML**

```
 <div class="row">
```

Either the form tag needed in my case or not

```
        <form>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="date" class="col-12 col-md-2 control-label"><?php echo 'Date';?> 
        </label>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
        <input type="text" class="datepicker form-control" name="date" id="date">
        </div>
        </div>
```

Here I am getting the data from my database

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="class_id" class="col-12 col-md-2 control-label"><?php echo 
         get_phrase('Select Class');?></label>
         <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
         <select name="class_id" class="form-control" id="class_id" onchange="return get_attendance()" >
         <option value=""><?php echo get_phrase('select class');?></option>
         <?php 
         $classes = $this->db->get('class')->result_array();
            foreach($classes as $row):?>
               <option value="<?php echo $row['class_id'];?>"><?php echo $row['name'];?></option>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
          </select>
          </div>
         </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

I am using datatable class for exporting and printing

```
    <table class="table table-bordered datatable" id="table_export">
        <thead>
             <tr>
                 <th>#</th>
                 <th><div><?php echo get_phrase('Status');?></div></th>
                 <th><div><?php echo get_phrase('Student Name');?></div></th>
                 <th><div><?php echo get_phrase('Class Name');?></div></th>
                 <th><div><?php echo get_phrase('Date');?></div></th>
                 <th><div><?php echo get_phrase('options');?></div></th>
             </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
              <?php
                  $count = 1;
                  foreach($attendance as $row):?>
```

$attendance is recieved from the controller in $this->load->view('backend/index', $page_data);

```
<tr>
                          <td><?php echo $count++;?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $row['status'];?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $row['student_id'];?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $row['class_id'];?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $row['date'];?></td>
                       </tr>
                  <?php endforeach; ?>
           </tbody>
     </table>
```

MY JavaScript

The script below alert() the class_id and date but do not pass anything to the controller function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function get_attendance() {

            var class_id = $('#class_id').val();
            var date = $('#date').val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                dataType:"json",
                data: {"class_id": class_id, "date": date},
                url: '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php?admin/manage_attendance',
                success: function (data) {

                }
            });
}


</script>
```

My Controller

If I give static value to `$date` and `$class_id` as `$date = '04-04-2018'; $class_id = 2;` inside `manage_attendance()` below it works but using `$this->input->post()` do nothing:

```
function manage_attendance()
    {
        if($this->session->userdata('admin_login')!=1)
            redirect(base_url() , 'refresh');


            $date = $this->input->post('date');
            $class_id = $this->input->post('class_id');

        $page_data['attendance']= $this->db->get_where('attendance', array('class_id' => $class_id , 'date' => $date))->result_array();

        $page_data['page_name']  =  'manage_attendance';
        $page_data['page_title'] =  get_phrase('manage_daily_attendance');
        $this->load->view('backend/index', $page_data);
    }
```

Comment: now what is the result/error your are facing

Comment: I am getting nothing from select.class_id.onchange

Comment: `url: '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php?admin/manage_attendance'` I think may be change to `url: '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/admin/manage_attendance',`

Comment: And where is that jQuery code? Have you gone through the typical debugging routes? What is your ajax returning? Can you narrow this down to a minimal, verifiable and complete example as per stacks guidelines?

Comment: @RyukLee no success by doing that

Comment: @Alex I have experimented the same by appending the $date and $class_id to url: '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php?admin/manage_attendance' + date + '/' + class_id, and changing my controller function to manage_attendance($date, $class_id) but i do not want this logic!

Comment: @Alex the script is internal to the html/view

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
url: '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php?admin/manage_attendance'
```

to

```
url: '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/admin/manage_attendance',
```

Answer (score 0):

I can get the same result by coding as following but I do not prefer that method/logic I want something as I have posted above

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="class_id" class="col-12 col-md-2 control-label"><?php echo 
         get_phrase('Select Class');?></label>
         <div class="col-12 col-md-3">
         <select name="class_id" class="form-control" id="class_id" onchange="return get_attendance()" >
         <option value=""><?php echo get_phrase('select class');?></option>
         <?php 
         $classes = $this->db->get('class')->result_array();
            foreach($classes as $row):?>
               <option value="<?php echo $row['class_id'];?>"><?php echo $row['name'];?></option>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
          </select>
          </div>
         </div>
        </form>
    </div>

<table class="table table-bordered datatable" id="table_export">
        <thead>
             <tr>
                 <th>#</th>
                 <th><div><?php echo get_phrase('Status');?></div></th>
                 <th><div><?php echo get_phrase('Student Name');?></div></th>
                 <th><div><?php echo get_phrase('Class Name');?></div></th>
                 <th><div><?php echo get_phrase('Date');?></div></th>
             </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody id="putdatahere">
         </tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function get_attendance() {
        var e = document.getElementById("class_id");
        var class_id = e[e.selectedIndex].value;
        var date = $('#date').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php?admin/manage_attendance/'+ date +'/' + class_id,
            success: function(response)
            {
                jQuery('#putdatahere').html(response);
               }
        });

    }
</script>
```

CodeIgniter Controller

```
function manage_attendance($date, $class_id){
      $query = $this->db->get_where('attendance', array('class_id' => $class_id , 'date' => $date))->result_array();

       if($query){
                        $html_return = "";
                        foreach ($query as $attendance) {
                            $html_return .="<tr><td>"; 
                            $html_return .= $attendance['status']; //further Proccessing here e.g if $attendance['status'] == 0 echo absent otherwise present
                            $html_return .="</td><td>";
                            $html_return .= $attendance['student_id']); //further Proccessing here e.g get student name from its student_id
                            $html_return .="</td><td>";
                            $html_return .= $attendance['class_id']; //further Proccessing here e.g get class name from its class_id
                            $html_return .= "</td><td>";
                            $html_return .= $attendance['date']; 
                            $html_return .="</td></tr>";
                        }

                        echo $html_return;
                    } else {
                        echo 'No record';
                    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You have to append data like this using jquery:

function get_attendance() {
            var class_id = $('#class_id').val();
            var date = $('#date').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                dataType:"json",
                data: {class_id: class_id, date: date},
            url: '<?php echo base_url();?>index.php?admin/manage_attendance',
                success: function (data) {

                var resultData = JSON.parse(response);

            if(resultData!=null){
                attendance= resultData.length;

            }
            if(attendance>0){

                for(i=0;i<attendance;i++){
                    $(".attendance_listing").append("<tr><td>"+resultData[i].status+"</td><td>"+resultData[i].student_id+"</td><td>"+resultData[i].class_id+"</td><td>"+resultData[i].date+"</td></tr>");
                }
            }


        }
    });
   }
   //controler
   function manage_attendance()
    {
        if($this->session->userdata('admin_login')!=1){
                redirect(base_url() , 'refresh');


                $date = $this->input->post('date');
                $class_id = $this->input->post('class_id');

                $page_data['attendance']= $this->db->get_where('attendance', array('class_id' => $class_id , 'date' => $date))->result_array();

                $page_data['page_name']  =  'manage_attendance';
                $page_data['page_title'] =  get_phrase('manage_daily_attendance');
                echo json_encode($page_data);
            }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, @Pooja Rani for your answer but I do not want to echo the result because it will just open a new blank page in my case. I want to load my view with $page_data['attendance'] as the second parameter and to do some further processing upon it when it become available inside my view